# Работа с json google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

Есть вот такой ответ json https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=59.926353,30.316785&language=ru
Так как на разные координаты приходят разные ответы,(поменяны местами,на какую то локацию больше информации на какую то меньше) необходимо обращаться к типу

```
            {
               "long_name" : "13",
               "short_name" : "13",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            }
```

В данной ситуации все просто

```
for(i=0;i<=countjson;i++)
          {
              if(data.results[0].address_components[i].types=='street_number')
                  {alert(data.results[0].address_components[i].long_name) } 
          }
```

Но как быть в такой ситуации

```
{
               "long_name" : "Санкт-Петербург",
               "short_name" : "СПБ",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            }
```

мне нужно только к 1 типу обратиться,к locality например.

А так же как лучше поступить мне нужно получить `страну,город,район,улицу` , но ответы всегда разные приходят,как быть? На одни координаты нужное мне  в первом результате во втором  в 0

Comment: это же варианты ответов, а не разные ответы.

Comment: про разные ответы ,это относятся ко 2 вопросу,как получить конкретные показатели `страну,город,район,улицу`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делал нечто подобное. Там все просто. Разберешься.

https://github.com/Sit138/Stock_4

На сколько я помню в каждом приходящем json есть именно тот ответ, который и нужно использовать при парсинге.